# Transfer data between listeners

Tags: java, android

I need to transfer `leftPinIndex` and `rightPinIndex` variables from one listener to another, when clicking on the button.

How can I do that better than now?

```
        final int[] a = new int[1];
        final int[] b = new int[1];

        rangebar.setOnRangeBarChangeListener(new RangeBar.OnRangeBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRangeChangeListener(RangeBar rangeBar,
                                              int leftPinIndex,
                                              int rightPinIndex,
                                              String leftPinValue,
                                              String rightPinValue) {
                //get leftPinIndex и rightPinIndex
                a[0] = leftPinIndex;
                b[0] = rightPinIndex;
            }

        resultButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            //get variables here from rangebar listener
            Log.i("variables: ", a[0] + " " + b[0]);
        });
```

Comment: why use final arrays when you could just use non-final fields?

Comment: @JohannesKuhn because Android studio says ```Variable 'a' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be final or effectively final```

Answer (score 0):

Ecapsualte you code into a function and pass the array as parameter or the function which needs to be called with `leftPinIndex` or `rightPinIndex`. Then you will access to the outer things otherwise you are in `RangBar` class and there is no way you return any value.(Call by reference).

```
  void performAction(int [] toCopyElem, Rangbar rangebar){
      rangebar.setOnRangeBarChangeListener(new RangeBar.OnRangeBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRangeChangeListener(RangeBar rangeBar,
                                              int leftPinIndex,
                                              int rightPinIndex,
                                              String leftPinValue,
                                              String rightPinValue) {
                //get leftPinIndex и rightPinIndex
                toCopyElem[0] = leftPinIndex;
                toCopyElem[1] = rightPinIndex;
                 //Or call the function.
            }


    }
```